# Why do MenuItem headers have underscores before them?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, menuitem

If you're declaring `MenuItem`s, I've always seen their `Header` properties declared like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Edit">
    <MenuItem Header="_Undo"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Redo"/>
</MenuItem>
```

instead of like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Edit">
    <MenuItem Header="Undo"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Redo"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Is there a reason for this or is it just a convention? In the designer it seems to affect nothing whether I have the underscore behind or not.

Comment: I'm guessing it's an old convention of using & to indicate the 'activating key' (char get's underscored in menu and can be used with alt-key) , but & doesn't fair well in average text, so they converted it to '_' since it represents the underscore stuff.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Its to designate the keyboard shortcut.

`"_Edit"` means that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> will activate that menu item, whereas

`"E_dit"` means that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will work.

Also, the underscored letter will have an underline when in focus to clue the user in to the keyboard shortcut.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Also: when displayed and in focus, the letter after the underscore is underlined.